# VS Code missing Git menus?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am trying to view the menus shown in the image below, in particular the stashes menu (I have several stashes pushed):

[image]

but all I see is :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inbuilt git doesn't have these options, you need to install [GitLens — Git supercharged](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension.